# Random non- overlapping spheres in a cube

Tags: matlab, geometry

I am trying to generate random spheres inside a cube model using MATLAB. I have posted one part of the code that am trying to develop. One constraint is to make sure the random sphere is bounded inside a cube. Radius is between (0.15 mm - 0.55 mm). 
Variable (dims) is the dimension of cube. dims = [ 10 10 10 ]
(Cube dimension is of 10mm * 10mm * 10mm)

```
function [ c, r ] = randomSphere( dims )
r = 0.15 + ( 0.55 - 0.15) .* rand(1);
x = (10 - r) * rand(1) + r;
y = (10 - r) * rand(1) + r;
z = (10 - r) * rand(1) + r;
c = [ x y z];
```

Any ideas on improving the code. All the co-ordinates generated are less than 1 i.e between (0,1). How should i scale the co ordinates? Say something like (3.5, 5.6, 6.7) is also bounded inside a cube.

Comment: just multiply and add according to your needs, for example `0.4*rand(1)+0.15` will generate a random # between 0.15 and 0.55 ...

Comment: @natan Yes! i have done that for 'r' which is the radius of sphere. I have a problem in determining co-ordinates or position of sphere inside a cube of size 10mm*10mm*10mm.

Comment: if you know how to generate a random number in an interval `[a b]` why cant you generate three random numbers in an interval `[a b]`?

Comment: Since, there is an additional constraint that the sphere co-ordinates has to be positioned within the dimension of cube.

Comment: which is just an interval `[a b]` in x, and interval `[a b]` in y, and an interval `[a b]` in z. You can set `a,b` as you wish. You can also just sample randomly in or out of the sphere and just check whether in was in the sphere afterwards, you'll still sample uniformly...

Comment: @natan How do you find the edits that i made in the code? Will these make sure the position of the sphere is bounded inside the cube with that random radius?

Comment: You almost got that right, you need to go to `(10 - 2*r) .* rand(...` instead, because you need to be in the range `[r 10-r]`. I'll write an answer that shows how to do this in a one liner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got that right, here's a way to do it:

```
function [ c, r ] = randomSphereGen()
r = 0.15 + ( 0.55 - 0.15) .* rand(1);
c = bsxfun(@times,(10 - 2*r) , rand(1,3)) + r;
```